# Crop CVPixelBuffer using the frame of the UIView

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I have the following problem: in my app I need to process video feed, frame-by-frame using `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and its delegate. It was all working well as long as I was processing the whole frame. Now, we have added the view representing area of interest in the view, which contains the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` (think of as target area for QR code scanning, a rectangle with rounded corners in the center of the screen). I need to use the frame of that view (representing target area / crosshair / wtw) to crop out the region of interest in `CVPixelBuffer` which I receive in `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`. Obviously, whatever region I crop in the pixel buffer should correspond with what user sees on screen (in target area), so that there is no discrepancy between what's being processed and what user expects to be processed.

Has anybody done something like this? Can it be done? Any help appreciated!

P.S. Using `AVCaptureMetadataOutput` is not an option.

P.P.S. I have no problem performing crop either with `CIImage` filters or with `vImage_Buffer`, I just can't get the right coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody needs this - it all comes down to the magic of the `AVRectMake` function. I found, that depending on its arguments you can simulate the trasform, which happens when `previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFit` or `previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill`

Here are two examples:

```
 let croppedRectFromCaptureDeviceFrame = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: captureDeviceFrame.size, // size of the CVPixelBuffer returned by AVCaptureVideoDataOutput

 insideRect: previewLayer.bounds) // size of the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
```

In this example the resulting rectangle, if used for cropping the `CVPixelBuffer`, will result in the image, which will be exactly like what you'd see in `previewLayer` with `videoGravity = .resizeAspectFit`. This makes sense and matches the sample code in the `AVMakeRect` documentation.

However, if you do it like this:

```
let croppedRectFromCaptureDeviceFrame = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio:privewLayer.frame.size,
 insideRect:captureDeviceFrame) // origin is .zero in captureDeviceFrame
```

Then you'll get an image (in the same way I described above), which would correspond to `previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill`. I'm not really sure why it happens - upon inspecting the resulting `CGRect` I found the it was moved horizontally to right (x != 0), and width and height were more, than `previewLayer.frame.size`  (I had 1920x1080 CVPixelBuffer and 828x1114 preview layer, the resulting CGRect was (0, 73..., 932, 1417), figures are not exact, but they are related to each other correctly). Perhaps, the offset undergone by the resulting `CGRect` is a result of some inherently asserted coordinate transfromation between `UIKit` and `AVFoundation`. In any case, since both `videoGravity` and `AVMakeRect` come from the same framework, I think it's ok to use this effect to achieve my goal, even though it's not entirely clear why this happens.

Once we have the frame of the image, which will be shown in a `previewLayer` it's easy to find the rect, which should be cropped, from that image using target area's frame (a transparent rectangle with a border, guiding user, where they should place QR code). It will be translated and scaled inside the frame we found via `AVMakeRect`. To put it in code:

```
let scaleFactor = previewLayer.frame.width / croppedRectFromCaptureDeviceFrame.size.width // it will be the same along both axes, because we preserved aspect:
let targetAreaCropFrame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:targetAreaSourceFrame.x+croppedRectFromCaptureDeviceFrame.x, y:same),size: CGSize(width:targetAreaSourceFrame.width*(1/scaleFactor), height:targetAreaSourceFrame.height*(1/scaleFactor)) // inverse scale factor, because we convert from previewLayer's frame
```

Crop then is performed by accessing bytes directly.